# ASP.NET: Store user information on submit

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, browser, ip

i'm kinda new into asp.net so i need some help.

i have this form, that the data is stored in a SQL db using Linq.

my question is, how can i add a column, that will have all the information about the sender, meaning IP address, browser, referrer etc.

the thing is is i want to store it in one field.

i come from a php knowledge that has been long forgotten by me, but i still remember there was some serialize command, that you could run on an array and store it in a db, then when you want it back to an array you would just run deserialize command and it would go back to an array.

so what you guys think the best way of preforming this action is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assemble the data in any serialized form yourself and save it to the DB column. One way could be to use xml format

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<userdata>");
sb.Append("<browser>").Append(Request.Browser.Browser).Append("</browser>");
sb.Append("<ipaddress>").Append(Request.UserHostAddress).Append("</ipaddress>");
sb.Append("<referrer>").Append(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri).Append("</referrer>");
sb.Append("</userdata>");

string SenderData = sb.ToString();
// Save the SenderData string to a varchar DB column.

// The above code only proposes the serialization idea.
// As commented, it doesn't encode the user values.
// One of the way to take care of that could be using XmlTextWriter.

var sb = new StringBuilder();

var xtw = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));

xtw.WriteStartElement("userdata");
xtw.WriteElementString("browser", Request.Browser.Browser);
xtw.WriteElementString("ipaddress", Request.UserHostAddress);
xtw.WriteElementString("referrer", Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
xtw.WriteEndElement();

xtw.Close();

string SenderData = sb.ToString();
// Save the SenderData string to a varchar DB column.

// Another suggested way

public class UserData
{
    public string Browser { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Referrer { get; set; }

    public UserData()
    {
    }

    public UserData(string browser, string iPAddress, string referrer)
    {
        Browser = browser;
        IPAddress = iPAddress;
        Referrer = referrer;
    }
}

var userData = new UserData(Request.Browser.Browser, Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);

var xmls = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(UserData));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var xtw = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));

xmls.Serialize(xtw, userData);

xtw.Close();

string SenderData = sb.ToString();
// Save the SenderData string to a varchar DB column.
```

Comment: Yes, but the code is a bad example of how to generate XML (none of the user-provided data is encoded as XML strings).

Comment: but what good is it to save it as XML? isn't a better way to serialize this information?

Comment: @Jacob -- it would be helpful to see a "good" example instead of just showing up and citing it as bad.

Comment: @Nati, what exactly do you want to serialize your data into, if not XML?

Comment: better to create a class and just use the XmlSerializer, but your solution will work :)

Comment: @Nati, XML is only one way to serialize. You can choose any other way you like. XML would help you get this data back in queries rater easily, as SQL server supports XML columns and can potentially present this data as if it were stored as separate columns. Any other way, you most likely would have to parse (deserialize) the data in the presentation layer.

Comment: @AaronS - are you the same AaronS from Lord of Ultima whose Castles I just took over the last couple of days?

Comment: i just want to store a few columns in one column, don't matter to me how, i simply want to put it there (meaning zip it somehow) and then when i fetch it back i want it to be easy to access (unzip it..)